# Ajax get with jsonp gives "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jsonp

I am using jQuery for GET request and getting a response in json format. But when I try to use it, it throws below error message in browser developer tools console.

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]  hosts:1:10 >>

Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",   
        url: url,   
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: { "filter": "host.vars.osgroup==\"unix\""},
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {
            accept:'application/json',
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        }
        // },
        // success : function(data)
        // {
        //     console.log(data);
        // }

})
 .done(function(html) {
     $("#displayElement").append(html);
 });
```

Comment: The error means that you're not getting valid JSONP data back. Note that JSON and JSONP are not interchangeable, so if you're attempting to use  JSONP to get around a CORS error then you have bigger problems to address first. Also note that `async: false` is terrible practice and should be removed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I am quite new to jquery and javascript, I tried to use 'json' as the datatype, but got '400 Wrong Accept header' error.
Could you please advise, how can I solve this in proper way.

Comment: In that case you should change back to JSON format. The issue is with how you authenticate with the server. There's not much we can really help with in regards to that

Answer (score 2):

This error occures just when the response of the server is not in valid JSONP format. To clear the things on you JSONP is not json. it is javascript script you can say. If you are using say Php then your php should output like this:

```
     header("Content-Type: application/json");    
     exit("mycallback(".json_encode(['error' => 0,'auth_token' => $_COOKIE['server_token']]).")");
```

You see that Php code is outputting a string which has javascript function call with json formatted data as parameter. Now in ajax call you should have everything stream-lined. Ajax call should be like this:

```
     $.ajax({
        url:'http://ssoidpclient.local/get_auth_token',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
        success:function(data)
        {
        }

     });
```